# Observer not working, string output shows only {"_eavConfig":{}} as value

Tags: magento2, event-observer

This is the code for my observe class, and it is working for the right event as I added a messageManager notice that appeared after the event.

All I want is the order information, I want the address. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
    <?php

    // Get proper class to extend.

    namespace Website\SalesTracker\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


    /**
    * 
    */
    class TrackOrder implements ObserverInterface
    {

        protected $_messageManager;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
        )
        {
            $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        }

        public function execute(
            \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
        )
        {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

            $string = json_encode($order);
            $string .= 'Working?';
            file_put_contents('/debug-data2.txt', $string);
            // var_dump($observer->getOrder());
        }
    }
```

Here is my events.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="sales_order_place_after">
            <observer name="sales_order_track" instance="Website\SalesTracker\Observer\TrackOrder" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

Comment: you can try with sales_order_save_after its works for you

Comment: Didn't work...?